# Next world chess championship

Tags: tournament, world-championship, candidates

When and where is the next world championship? Also, when is the candidates? Where can I find the important chess tournaments online?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When and where is the next world championship?

It will take place in 2020 at the end of the year. The exact date and location have not been revealed nor decided yet.

> When is the Candidates?

In 2020, the same year as the world championship match. It usually takes place in March, but [no official information](https://www.fide.com/component/content/article/1-fide-news/10950-bidding-opens-to-host-the-2020-world-chess-candidates-tournament-.html) about it has been released yet.

> Where can I find the important chess tournaments online?

If you are asking about the dates, then there are many sources. The one I use is [2700chess](https://2700chess.com). Scroll down to the "Future Events" section. It lists many scheduled upcoming tournaments as well as the most notable players taking part in each. There is also the [Chess.com tournaments calendar](https://www.chess.com/article/view/chess-tournaments-calendar).

If you are asking about the broadcasts of the tournaments, then either [Chess24](https://chess24.com/en/watch/live-tournaments) or [Chess.com](https://www.chess.com/events) is the right place for you. Personally I use Chess24.

Comment: There's a high probability it will be somewhere in Norway

Comment: Yes, especially that Norway was very close to hosting the 2018 match.

Answer (score 5):

> Where can I find the important chess tournaments online?

Tournaments like the Candidates and World Championships are FIDE events. News about them will appear first on the [FIDE](https://www.fide.com/index.php) website. FIDE also have a [Twitter account](https://twitter.com/FIDE_chess) which you can follow which will also make shorter announcements usually with links back to stories on the FIDE website.